# PGAdmin error when Registering a server with AWS RDS - "Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I have created a Postgre RDS through AWS, and am trying to register it within pgAdmin, but every single thing I do i still am unable to connect to the server.

I get the same generic error over and over again.

The three most recommended solutions are to

- Make the DB public
- Change the inbound rules for the security group
- Change the port in either inbound rules or DB configuration

I have done all three of these. Additionally I have

- Tried different ports in case of a firewall blocking a certain port
- Every combination of inbound rules (all traffic, my ip, all ip)
- All recent installs of pgAdmin
- running the DB on different PostGre versions

I really am stuck and don't know what to do. I am on page four of google, and hour 5 of looking for a solution and will give up soon.

If there are any solutions or workarounds to this, they would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is your DB in a public subnet?

Comment: @FilippoTestini I thought it was but I was wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that my DB was not in a public subnet.

I thought it was, but I was looking at the wrong subnet group.

If you are experiencing similar issues, and are using nothing but auto-generated/default configuration for your resources in aws like I was - I did the following

-I had to create a new VPC (you can not change subnet groups that are tied to your aws RDS if they are in the same VPC)

-Create a new Internet Gateway

-Create new subnets and make sure they target the IGW

-(Additionally make sure DNS Hostname is enabled in your VPC config or you will not be able to attach your DB to the VPC)

-Configure a new route table and attach the subnets and also make it the main route table

-Make sure the route table is targeting the IGW

-Create a new subnet group with the subnets you created

-Configure the DB so that it is attached to the new VPC, and the new subnet group

-Finally, this will reset your inbound rules on the DB so make sure they are still public.

This is probably not the proper way to accomplish this, but it worked, and is a solution to the original problem.

To tell if your Subnets are public vs private -> if they are private they will only target 'local'